# Default UIKeyboardType for iPad for UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, uikeyboardtype

I have a hidden button that brings up a UIKeyboard for a UISearchBar by making the UISearchBar the first responder.  I've tried changing the keyboardtype to different keyboards like so:

```
self.SearchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
```

but I continue to get the same keyboard on default with the letters first.  Is there a way to default on the numbers since I only need numbers for the iPad?  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you set the keyboard type before the UISearchBar view is actually loaded. Have you checked that self.searchBar is not nil the moment you set the keyboard type?

Comment: ah, you found that out by yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the answer is that keyboardType must be set when the searachBar is created like in viewDidLoad for example to take effect.